# ankhSVN: project files and source code in different location

Tags: ankhsvn

I have my VS2012 solution file in a directory separate from my source code files (code is on the same drive but no child folder of the solution folder).

Now when I add my solution to the repository via ankhSVN, in the dialog I can only choose the folder where my solution file resides (or parent folder paths of it). And once the solution is added, the source files that are in the underlying project are not added to the repository (apparently because they are nowhere to be found inside the solution folder).

So my question is, how can I make it add my source files as well to the repository?